# Hide modeless form when all macros stop

Tags: vba, forms, excel, triggers

First of all I want to thank everyone who has helped me with answers here. You guys have been important in my development and for that you have my respect.

For the question: I want to create a form that displays the status for running multiple macros in sequence. For that i'm showing a form modelees so the macros continue running in the background.

The way I have it setup now, the form remains visible after macros are done.

Is there a way i can trigger the form to hide/unload when no macro is running?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Just unload the form at the end of the last macro. I assume you have one calling sub which handles showing the form and calling the macros, so that is where I would also hide the progress form.